# How to create copying items from property values?

Tags: msbuild

Let's say I have a list of sub paths such as

```
 <PropertyGroup>
   <subPaths>$(path1)\**\*; $(path2)\**\*; $(path3)\file3.txt; </subPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I want to copy these files from folder A to folder B (surely we already have all the sub folders/files in A). What I try was:

```
<Target Name="Replace" DependsOnTargets="Replace_Init; Replace_Copy1Path">
</Target>

<Target Name="Replace_Init">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <subPaths>$(path1)\**\*; $(path2)\**\*; $(path3)\file3.txt; </subPaths>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <subPathItems Include="$(subPathFiles.Split(';'))" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="Replace_Copy1Path" Outputs="%(subPathItems.Identity)">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <src>$(folderA)\%(subPathItems.Identity)</src>
    <dest>$(folderB)\%(subPathItems.Identity)</dest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(src)" DestinationFiles="$(dest)" />
</Target>
```

But the Copy task didn't work. It doesn't translate the `**\*` to files. What did I do wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do something like that.

`$(subPathFiles.Split(';'))` returns a property where value are separated by semicolon, so this call is useless.

If you want to keep this mechanism you should use the task `StringToItemCol` from [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/) :

```
<Target Name="Replace_Init">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <subPaths>$(path1)\**\*; $(path2)\**\*; $(path3)\file3.txt; </subPaths>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <MsBuildHelper TaskAction="StringToItemCol" 
                 ItemString="$(subPaths)" Separator=";">
    <Output TaskParameter="OutputItems" ItemName="subPathItems "/>
  </MsBuildHelper>
</Target>
```

Otherwise, you could directly pass items with folderA and subPaths embedded :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <subPathIt Include="$(folderA)\$(path1)\**\*"/>
  <subPathIt Include="$(folderA)\$(path2)\**\*"/>
  <subPathIt Include="$(folderA)\$(path3)\file3.txt" Condition="Exists('$(path3)\file3.txt')"/>
</ItemGroup>


<Target Name="Replace_Copy1Path">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(subPathItems )" 
        DestinationFiles="$(folderB)\%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks madgnome! But as you said, if we do <ItemGroup> <files Include="$(folderA)\**\*; $(folderB)\**\*"/> </ItemGroup> , we won't have @files which contains all files in folderA and folderB, right?

Comment: Right. You have to write two separate <files Include="$(folderX)...">

Comment: Dear madgnome, I don't think so. I've just double checked and see that if I declare like above, all files are recursively added into files. So strange!

Comment: My bad, semicolon can be used inside item includes to separate multiple item lists.

Comment: You could use semicolon inside an item definition to separate multiple item lists. Does that answer your question?